# Parity/sign of the string reversal permutation as a function of length

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

Suppose I have a string of length $n$, such as

12345 (when $n=5$)

or more generally,

123($\ldots$)$n$.

I want to reverse the string, so that 12345 becomes 54321. This reversal can be thought of as a permutation $\sigma$ of the characters in the string.

What I would like to know is, *what is the parity of the reversal permutation, given as a function of the string length (the number of elements)?*

For example, for $n= 1, 2, 3, 4$, the reversal parities are even, odd, odd, even respectively.

**Partial work:** Equivalently, we just need to know the value of the function $f(n) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \mod 2$, since the number of elementary permutations in a reversal can just be counted as an arithmetic series (e.g. for '1234', '4' gets moved to the left three times, '3' two times, etc.)

**Background:** From *Geometric algebra for Physicists*, Chapter 2. There's an operator called 'reversion' defined in the text that reverses the elements of a wedge product. Since the wedge product is anti-commutative, the sign of the result is given by the parity of the permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's study the values of $f$:

if $n=4k$, then $f(n)= (2k)(4k-1)= 0 \mod 2$.

if $n=4k+1$, then $f(n)= (4k+1)(2k) = 0 \mod 2$.

if $n=4k+2$, then $f(n)= (2k+1)(4k+1)= 1 \mod 2$.

if $n=4k+3$, then $f(n)= (4k+3)(2k+1)= 1 \mod 2$.

Comment: Worth noting that the sequence forms the triangular numbers (0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 34, ...) which are even, odd, odd, even, even, odd, odd, even, even, etc. Because even + odd = odd and odd + odd = even, this pattern continues forever.