# Calculate determinant of $n$-th order

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have problem with creating a upper triangular matrix (in order to calculate the determinant) of the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  2&  3&  ...& n-2 &n-1  &1 \\ 
 1&  2&  3&  ...&  n-2&  1&n \\ 
 1&  2&  3&  ...&  1&n-1  &n \\ 
 .&  .&  .&  .&  .&  .& \\
 .&  .& .& .& .& .& \\
 1&  2&  1&  ...& n-2 &n-1  &n \\ 
 1&  1&  3&  ...&  n-2& n-1 &n \\ 
 1&  2&  3&  ...&  n-2& n-1 &n 
\end{pmatrix}$$

One of my attempts included subtracting the first row from the others which got me to this point:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  2&  3&  ...& n-2 &n-1  &1 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  ...&  0&  2-n&n-1 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  ...&  3-n&0 &n-1 \\ 
 .&  .&  .&  .&  .&  .& \\
 .&  .& .& .& .& .& \\
 0&  0&  -2&  ...& 0 &0 &n-1 \\ 
 0&  -1&  0&  ...&  0&0 &n-1 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  ...&  0&0 &n-1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Any ideas on how to move on from here ?

Comment: $n$ has to be odd, right ? For $n = 4$, we get a $5 \times 4$ matrix. Is it really necessary for you to get an upper triangular matrix (maybe this is requested in an exercise?) or you can apply another method? With what you have done, it is enough to develop the determinant with respect to the first column, next you can develop with respect to the last row and the last column and so on.

Comment: Use Wolfram Alpha or something to get the answers for $n=1,2,3,4,5$ and then insert that into OEIS to see if you get a known sequence.

Comment: @Sarvesh Ravichandran Iyer : no need to look for OEIS ;
 I have numerical computations : for $n=1,2,3...$ we get $ 1 ,1 ,-2,-6,24,120,   -720,-5040,40320...$ : the connection with factorials with appropriate signs is evident.

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh yeah, a clear pattern! In fact, following the OP's first step, there are so many zeros that an appropriate sequence of Laplace expansions should yield what you need (and tracking the positions of the cofactors will tell you the sign).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer but we're expected to calculate it by getting an upper or lower triangular matrix ... that's what I'm stuck on

Comment: @JeanMarie yes sorry, I was a bit disturbed by the head of this matrix, you're right of course. Thank you.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer By permuting the second row with the penultimate one, you change the determinant by a factor $-1$ (recall that this kind of operation is just the multiplication of your matrix by a certain permutation matrix), maybe it can help you.

Comment: @NaNoS Thanks, that is worth thinking about. For now, what I see is that swapping sufficiently many rows leads to a matrix which is upper triangular except for its first row. The point is, I think plain Gaussian elimination actually leads to some zero entries getting wiped out. So we have to be smarter here.

Comment: @NaNoS I don't have enough time but if you could write an answer : let's call the rows $R_1,\ldots,R_n$ and columns as $C_1,\ldots,C_n$. Then, we first do $R_1 = R_1 - R_2$, that makes $R_1$ into $[0,\ldots,0,n-2,1-n]$. Then, you do $C_{n-1} \to C_{n-1} - \frac{n-2}{1-n}C_2$, this will make the first row completely zero. You only need to track the diagonal entries because you're computing the determinant. I believe this can be repeated, now you do $R_2 = R_2-R_3$ and then $C_{n-2} = ...$ and something should be repeatable. Kindly check this and write an answer if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I didn't see your message, oups ! I see that Jean Marie made a clear answer, the author might be happy with it.

Comment: @NaNoS Agreed, but my approach will differ from that one and I still don't have time so someone else can convert it to a comment. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a first step, let us switch to the matrix with columns' order completely reversed :

$$M_n=\begin{pmatrix}
 \color{red}{1}&  (n-1)&   (n-2)&  ...& 3 &2  &1 \\ 
 n&  \color{red}{1}&   (n-2) & ...  &3&  2& 1 \\ 
 n&   (n-1)&  \color{red}{1}&  ...&  3&2  &1 \\ 
 .&  .&  .&  .&  .&  .& \\
 .&  .& .& .& .& .& \\
 n&   (n-1)&  (n-2)&  ...& \color{red}{1} &2  &1 \\ 
 n&   (n-1)&  (n-2)&  ...& 3& \color{red}{1} &1 \\ 
 n&   (n-1)&   (n-2)&  ...& 3& 2 &\color{red}{1} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

in this way the disrupting $\color{red}{"1"}$ entries are now situated on the main diagonal.

Remark : Changing the order of the columns of a matrix only changes the sign of its determinant (it is multiplied by the signature of the permutation).

The key fact comes from the following factorization :

$$M_n=P_nQ_n\tag{1}$$

where

$$P_n=\left(\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
1&-(n-1)&&&&&&\\
1&&-(n-2)&&&&&\\
1&&&-(n-3)&&&&\\
 .&  .& .& .& .& .& .&\\
1&&&&&&&-1\\
\hline
1&&&&&&&\end{array}\right)$$

and

$$Q_n=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
n&(n-1)&&.&3&2&1\\
\hline
1&0&&&&0&0\\
0&1&&&&0&0\\
&&1&&&&\\
 .&  .& .& .& .& .& \\
0&&&&&1&0\end{array}\right)$$

I have generaly replaced $0$ by void places, but in some cases where their presence clarify the situation.

(relationship (1) can be verified by block computations.)

Now, we can conclude because

$$\det(P_n)=(-1)^{(n-1)}.(-1)^{(n-1)} . (n-1)!=(n-1)!$$

(Laplace expansion along the first column) and

$$\det(Q_n)=(-1)^{(n-1)}$$

(expansion along the last column).

Don't forget, in a final step, to take into account the signature of the initial permutation which is rather peculiar (see results in this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2377870/305862)).

Numerical results :

for $n=1,2,3...$ we get resp. $1,1,−2,−6,24,120,−720,−5040,40320...$

If you want to verify, here is the little Matlab program I have used :

```
 for n=1:10;
    M=ones(n,1)*(n:-1:1)-diag((n-1):-1:0);% initial
    P=[ones(n-1,1),-diag(n-1:-1:1);1,zeros(1,n-1)];
    Q=[(n:-1:1);eye(n-1),zeros(n-1,1)];
    M-P*Q, % always zero
    T(n)=det(M);
 end
 T
```

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

We could use the Cauchy determinant formula

$$\det(A + B C) = \det A + C \operatorname{adj}(A) B$$

where $A$ is $n\times n$, $B$ is $n\times 1$, and $C$ is  $1 \times n$, $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $A$.

Now we have $B= (1,2,\ldots, n)^t$, $C= (1,1,\ldots,1)$, and $A = \operatorname{diag}(0,-1, \ldots, -n)$. Now $A + B C$ is the matrix obtained by permuting the columns, like @Jean Marie: did.   Note that $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ has only one non-zero element $(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!$ at position $(1,1)$. This simplifies the problem a lot. Will skip the details.